# Format to include attachment in SendMail C#

Tags: c#

I'm not sure how to add an attachment to my SendMail function. Lets say i want to add "C:\test.pdf" as an attachment to my email, how do i add this from the SendMail function?

My User Side Code:

```
string attachment = "c:\test.pdf";

objEmail.SendMail(EmailTo, EmailFrom, Subject, "", attachment, System.Net.Mail.MailPriority.High, "", "", true);
```

Function Code:

```
public void SendMail(string mailTo, string mailFrom, string mailSubject, string mailBody, string[] mailAttachment, System.Net.Mail.MailPriority mailImportance, string mailCC, string mailBCC, bool mailBodyType)
```

Comment: the function is calling for "string[] mailAttachment" but i'm not sure how to format that from my "attachment" string on my user side code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what method `SendMail` is but you need to create an array like this:

```
string attachment = "c:\test.pdf";
string[] attachments =  new string[] { attachment };
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the `System.Net.Mail SmtpClient` and `System.Net.Mail.MailMessage` classes, and wrapping them with your method, then you need to just use the `MailMessage.Attachments` property (an AttachmentCollection).

For example:

```
// specify the smtp connection
SmtpClient client = new SmtpClient("mail.yourdomain.com");

// create a MailMessage
MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
mail.From = new MailAddress("address@yourdomain.com");
mail.To.Add(new MailAddress("address@sample.com");
mail.Subject = "EMail With Attachment";
mail.Body = "Please see attached document.";

// create an attachment
string pathToAttachment = @"\path\to\test.pdf";
mail.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(pathToAttachment));

// send the MailMessage
client.Send(mail);
```

Comment: this will work, but for what i already had, the oskar nailed what i was looking for. thanks though, i'll save this.